# Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate android

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have this error in android

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a
> 14745612 byte allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 9MB until OOM
> at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(BitmapFactory.java)

Tried all the solution like

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
        & android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
 and  
 dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "12g"
    }
```

& not declared any views as static and also used

```
System.gc();
```

but still showing error here

```
Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view)
 {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
       
 Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);

        view.layout(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(),
                view.getBottom());

        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Dont try to create bitmaps with a too big resolution.

Comment: You are attempting to create a 1920 x 1920 `Bitmap` (or something similarly sized). Your app does not have a single contiguous memory block big enough for that.

Comment: i have to get the the image from the view i didnt given specific size of bitmap its taking automatically